# Selecting an element from the dropdown on selenium webdriver using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
>       **def test_void_try(self):
>             driver = self.driver
>             driver.get(self.base_url + '********')
>             driver.find_element_by_id('IDToken1').clear()
>             driver.find_element_by_id('IDToken1').send_keys('****')
>             driver.find_element_by_id('IDToken2').clear()
>             driver.find_element_by_id('IDToken2').send_keys('****')
>             driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
>             self.wait_for(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Search').click()
>             driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="Search"]').click()
>             select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('navbarCollapse'))
>         
>             # Select by visible text
>         
>             select.select_by_visible_text('Search')
>             driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='navbarCollapse']/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a"
>                                          ).click()
>         
>             driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='new_batch_search']/div[2]/div[13]/div[1]/button"
>                                          ).click()
>             driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
>             driver.find_element_by_css_selector('label > input[type="search"]'
>                     ).clear()**
```

---

> ```
> <document>
>     <html>
>
>     <head>
>
>         <body data-turbolinks="true">
>             <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md fixed-top bg-inverse my-nav navbar-custom navbar-light">
>                 <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
> ```
>
> aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
>   data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
>                           
>                               
>                                   
>                                   
>                                       
>                                           
>                                               
>       Search
>
> Batch
>
> Transaction

Comment: It can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390161/using-selenium-to-find-elements-related-to-drop-down-list-from-another-frame-p/

Answer (score 2):

Use the Select class and it's `.select_by_visible_text()` method:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  

dropdown_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "<ID NO>")))              // To wait until the element appears on the page

select = Select(dropdown_element)  //To select the dropdown
select.select_by_visible_text("<Option>")    //To select the dropdown option
```

Note that you can also replace the "by ID" with "by xpath".